# Check stored value using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I’m looking for the fastest way to get all objectIDs of a collection with a privacy value 'public'.

[image]

In this image, privacy's value is 'public', so node should give me the '_id' of this object (in this example '57bc4b9f466fab7c099a3f94').

My attempt:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/databasename');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var collectionsNameSchema = new Schema({
    updated: {type: Date },
    privacy: { type: Object }
}, {collection: 'spots'});
var collectionsNameData = mongoose.model('collectionsNameData', collectionsNameSchema);

...

collectionsNameData.find({privacy: 'public'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i see you have a problem in query to mongoDB.

Try like this.

```
collectionsNameData.find({'privacy.value': 'public'});
```

This should return desired result.
You also may want to use projection as second parameter in find to return only fields that you want. Keep in mind that _id returned by default.

Hope this helps.